# Twoway estpost tabstat-esttab: retain variable labels

Tags: stata

I want to describe characteristics of cars by origin, and retrieve the result as latex table:

```
sysuse auto 
estpost tabstat price trunk, by(foreign) statistics(mean sd) columns(statistics) listwise nototal 
esttab using test.txt, main(mean) aux(sd)
```

Already after the estpost I can feel that the labels are going missing: it correctly displays the value labels "Domestic" and "Foreign", but simply lists the variables as "price" and "trunk" instead of "Price" and "Trunk space".

I have seen this problem on the internet, but no solution is satisfactory. Some suggest `fsum`, but that doesn't really allow latex, and also no cross-tabulation (means of x by category y).
How can I fix this?

I automatized the accepted's answer as follows:

```
local varlabels
foreach var in price trunk {
        local varlabels `"`varlabels' `var' "`:variable label `var''""'       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `varlabels` option allows you to add custom labels. After the `estpost` command the names of the estimates look like this:

```
. mat l e(mean)

e(mean)[1,4]
       Domestic:  Domestic:   Foreign:   Foreign:
          price      trunk      price      trunk
mean  6072.4231      14.75  6384.6818  11.409091
```

You can replace these names with variable labels with the addition of some code:

```
sysuse auto 
estpost tabstat price trunk, by(foreign) statistics(mean sd) columns(statistics) listwise nototal 

foreach name in `:colfullnames e(mean)' {
    foreach var in price trunk {
        if strpos("`name'", "`var'") > 0 {
            local varlabels `"`varlabels' `name' "`:variable label `var''""'
        }
    }
}

di `"`varlabels'"'
esttab, main(mean) aux(sd) varlabels(`varlabels')
```

Result:

```
. di `"`varlabels'"'
 Domestic:price "Price" Domestic:trunk "Trunk space (cu. ft.)" Foreign:price "Price" Foreign:trunk "Trunk space (cu. ft.)"

. esttab, main(mean) aux(sd) varlabels(`varlabels')

----------------------------
                      (1)   
                            
----------------------------
Domestic                    
Price              6072.4   
                 (3097.1)   
Trunk.. ft.)        14.75   
                  (4.306)   
----------------------------
Foreign                     
Price              6384.7   
                 (2621.9)   
Trunk.. ft.)        11.41   
                  (3.217)   
----------------------------
N                      74   
----------------------------
mean coefficients; sd in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

When adding option `unstack` to esttab, Domestic and Foreign are used as column names and the names of the coefficients are only price and trunk, so you could do something like this:

```
esttab, main(mean) aux(sd) unstack varlabels(price "`:variable label price'" trunk "`:variable label trunk'")
```

Comment: This looks great. Unfortunately, when I went back to my actual code (I'm not so much into cars), I realized that the code stops working when I add "unstack" as an option to esttab: the labels disappear again? I'm sorry for having to ask again, but while this answer taught me a great deal on how to set up a list of elabels, I have no idea why the stacked labels won't work no longer..

Comment: Great! Perhaps you want to include my automation of your updated answer which I have included in my question.